# strapi api not showing image field info

Tags: strapi

I'm new to using strapi.

I have created a "events" Collection Type.

My events collection type has the following fields (pls take note of the image field)

1. name
2. slug
3. venue
4. address
5. date
6. time
7. performers
8. description
9. image

When I go to http://localhost:1337/api/events

I get the following json which **does not** contain info of the image field.  This is a problem.
Why is the info for **image** not showing?  What should I do to make the image info included in the json returned from the api?

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"attributes":{"name":"Throwback Thursday with DJ Manny Duke","slug":"throwback-thursday-with-dj-manny-duke","venue":"Horizon Club","address":"919 3rd Ave New York, New York(NY), 1002","date":"2022-07-20T02:00:00.000Z","time":"10:00 PM","createdAt":"2022-04-12T02:05:08.246Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-12T02:17:16.760Z","publishedAt":"2022-04-12T02:05:16.192Z","performers":"DJ Manny Duke","description":"Description for the vent of DJ Manny Duke"}},{"id":2,"attributes":{"name":"Boom Dance Festival Experience","slug":"boom-dance-festival-experience","venue":"Blackjacks","address":"123 Lexington","date":"2022-04-25T16:00:00.000Z","time":"8:00 PM","createdAt":"2022-04-12T02:26:32.123Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-12T02:26:33.540Z","publishedAt":"2022-04-12T02:26:33.538Z","performers":"DJ LUKE, DJ BLACKJACK","description":"Whatever Description"}},{"id":3,"attributes":{"name":"Encore Night Boat Party","slug":"encore-night-boat-party","venue":"Encore","address":"12343 New York","date":"2022-11-14T16:00:00.000Z","time":"7:00 PM","createdAt":"2022-04-12T02:28:06.028Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-12T02:28:36.292Z","publishedAt":"2022-04-12T02:28:07.622Z","performers":"BAD BOY BILL","description":"Description of Encore"}}],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":25,"pageCount":1,"total":3}}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images data will not show without populating it. You need to use something like this `http://localhost:1337/api/events?populate=yourImage`

replace `yourImage` with the property name you are using in your strapi for images

Comment: This image field has too much data, how can we control that?

Comment: @FaisalShahzad did you figure out a way to do this natively in strapi

Comment: @MSadiq no man, I'm still overriding the result with .map to filter our unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 0):

@faisal-shahzad You can specify what fields to return from populated data using the `fields` parameter.

e.g. to populate only the image url and altText (and using the `qs` library to parse query object):

```js
import qs from "qs"

const queryObject = {
  populate: {
    yourImage: {
      fields: ["url", "alternativeText"]
    }
  }
}

const apiQuery = qs.stringify(queryObject, { encode: false });

console.log(apiQuery)
// populate[yourImage][fields][0]=url&populate[yourImage][fields][1]=alternativeText
```

More details in strapi docs: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#combining-population-with-other-operators